# UITableViewCell's isHighlighted property resets itself. Why, and can this be prevented?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm implementing a list where the first tap on an entry highlights it and takes one action, and the second tap takes another action.

I thought I'd set the cell's isHighlighted property on the first tap, and then check it the next time to detect a second tap.

This doesn't work: On the second tap, I find that the cell's isHighlighted property has been reset. I don't see anything about this in the Apple doc, or in any of the IB settings for the tableview or cell.

I have a simple custom cell class, so I can put my own Boolean in there to record the "highlighted" state. But I'd like to know why the built-in one doesn't work.

Comment: Unclear. A cell always passes through highlighted and selected on a tap. You cannot set it to be highlighted. Why can’t you just respond to its being selected, save that information, and respond specially to a tap if it was selected previously?

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm doing. But according to the Apple docs, you can indeed set it to be highlighted.  They even go into detail that if you use isHighlighted, you don't have the option of animating the transition; but if you use setHighlighted, you do.

Comment: You should never rely on the cell to track your application state;  This should be something in your data model or view model

Comment: Those states exist for cells but in real life the table view manages them, not you. You cannot undermine that.